# Sockets C++ - Nonblocking or Select approach

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

this is something I've been through a few times and after a short break I am coming back with an application for a client, but just want to remember a few things before I actually implement anything.

I will be speaking about a multi-client server here, that deals with clients connecting through TCP onto a server bound port.

I remember coding this by using select() , FD_ISSET, FD_ZERO, FD_SET - and it's family methods to accept and manage a list of connected clients on my server - and I remember it was working great, but this time it is about a simple 32 player RPG game - so nothing fast-paced, thus the TCP here.

Simple GO_TO packets, WEATHER change, TIME updates, TEXT messages, ITEM STATE CHANGES and QUITS, LOGINS ( broadcasts ) , and something else I can't find out now.

What stops me from sleeping today is what should I really choose to have this server running smoothly ( when speaking of it's networking performance ).

People tend to speak much about 'non-blocking' approach to sockets either by using ioctlsocket(..) or some other 'threading' weirdos, which do the thing but you have to controll them in a different style - and yes I have tried this, and have seen many approaches - which deal with many threads around in the application - what is kind of overcomplicated really..

I have seen those MSDN "ASYNCHROUNOUS" sockets too, where you get the messages from the socket - but this is too much I think.

So instead of coding I am thinking and would like to ask,

- if select() can do the trick when speaking of a game server, handling let's say those 32 players simultanously. What I mean here is how do you think from your experience, will that do the thing? Or I would have to rollback at the end and modify the whole server code while closing to the deadline..
- what exactly is the difference between doing select / ioctlsocket ?
- what are the pros and cons for both methods ?

Many many thanks for any reply to this, I hope I am clear in what I am asking about.

Comment: put an abstraction layer between processing and the network code. this way you can swith the network layer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select-style server could easily handle this small amount of concurrent clients, even on modest hardware.

Put readability first and choose the easiest solution, based on your experience. If you have done a similar implementation with select in the past then don't worry about performance.

In my experience on blocking IO is harder to get right at the first attempt, then the select way, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really serious about doing any more advanced networing stuff in C++ you definitively should consider using [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/), there is nothing "over-complicated" about it really, once you understand it's philosophy. And having 32 player support will eventually lead you into the clutches of threading anyway, so why not start today?

Also important is the question of handling dead connections, unresponsive clients, and any update to the game state while the game is waiting for network input. How do you plan on resolving that?

Comment: Well speaking of handling 'dead' connections i used to implement a sort of a 'ping timeout' mechanism, so server was sending ping requests to clients, who were required to reply with PONG - if there was no PONG packet to server from client for more than X seconds, connection was closed, broadcast was sent, and client was deleted.

On the other hand, having select() on socket's doesn't mean you won't know the client connection status - this is done with recv() returning <0,0,>0 - that tells you what you need.